# [Android ]How to get redirected url on Android app

Tags: android, http, redirect, kotlin

in android app, I want to get redirected URL

in my app, I want to play HLS(.m3u8) file
before access to HLS's URL we access other URL to redirect.

I coded as below but it doesn't work

```
val conn = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
conn.instanceFollowRedirects
conn.connect()

val inputStream :InputStream = con.inputStream
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(con.url.path)
inputStream.close()
```

I tried direct url to `.m3u8` and it works as below

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(con.url.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTTP Response. If the status code is between 300 and 399 it means that the page is being redirected to another page. To determine the destination read the "Location" header field:

```
object RedirectHelper {

    fun getRedirectUrl(connection: HttpURLConnection): String? {
        val code = connection.responseCode
        return if (code in 300..399) {
            connection.getHeaderField("Location")
        } else null
    }
}
```